# What is the benefit of the sensor marker?

Tags: sensor, body

I know that this marker on my Canon EOS shows me where my sensor is:

[image: image showing camera body]

Form technical point of view this is interesting, but is there benefit for me as a photographer to know exactly on which level my sensor is?

Is there a similar marker on DSLR of other brands, like Nikon?

Comment: To answer your second question. It's the same marker pretty much everywhere, and it's on all serious cameras of any make (including Nikon, etc...).

Comment: See also [What does the theta symbol near the flash represent?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8994/what-does-the-theta-symbol-near-the-flash-represent)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an "image plane indicator"?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21926/what-is-an-image-plane-indicator)

Comment: Hmm... the recommended duplicate isn't asking the same question, it's just by chance that the answer there contains relevant information.

Comment: @mattdm. Thanks for the links to the other questions -> Helps me also. Thinks that is not a duplicate in question self, but sure the answers overlap.

Comment: @John From the other question: "... and what is it used for?"

Comment: @mattdm - But buried though... I think they're similar myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is used to precisely measure the distance of the subject from the camera. so you can adjust the focus on the distance scale on your lens. it is also used to determine(calculate) the reproduction ratio / Macro Mode Maximum Magnification.

Comment: Thanks for answer (+1 for that). Very interesting point. So you need the marker (only) for very precise measurements?

Comment: at least as far as i know. and i haven't found anything more about this topic. thanks for up