# How can I find the sensor position on my camera?

Tags: sensor, canon-600d, image-plane

In terms of post production I need to measure the exact distance from the camera sensor to several objects on the set.

Where I can find specifications to determine the sensor position of a canon 600D?

Comment: I answered yours, can you answer [mine](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/59742/10147)? :-)

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46336/15871

Comment: Thanks @MichaelClark! You are right, the answers are similar, but the question is not - the issues are different. Of people searching for my issue, they won't type: "reference plane" or "focus distance". That's why I don't think that this is really a duplicate. I'm asking for: the position of the sensor on the camera.

Comment: Can you put a little more about why you *are* looking into the question? That will help this get reopened.

Comment: Thanks @mattdm! Something like this?

Comment: @poor When a question is closed it still will show up in search results, and the finder will be directed to the original question.

Comment: @MichaelClark You are the moderator :) Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most DSLR cameras have a sign on the top ([Plimsoll mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterline)) which looks sort of like

[image]

The line indicates the position of the sensor plane.

I googled for pictures of the 600D.  It also has this indicator on the left side of the camera top.

[image]