# Why is the autofocus not working on my Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II USM?

Tags: lens, canon, dslr, autofocus, focus-motor

I bought the EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II lens and the autofocus is not working. It's non-functional. I can use the lens in manual mode but not in autofocus. What could be the cause?

Comment: Jus a picky question: there is a switch on a left side of the lens labeled AF/M. Have you tried both positions?

Comment: Are you able to test the lens on another body?

Comment: On which camera body? Do you use an adapter? Have you bought a new one or used?

Comment: I've read that the autofocus doesn't work on the Canon EOS 70D. Is that your camera body?

Answer (score 5):

Possible reasons why the AF on your EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II lens isn't working:

- The *AF/MF* switch is set to *MF* (manual focus).
- You are attempting to focus an object at a distance from the camera, as measured from the [*focal plane mark*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46329/what-is-the-reference-plane-used-when-the-minimum-focus-distance-is-measured) on the camera body, that is less than the MFD (minimum focus distance) of the lens or is less than the distance limited by the *Focus Limiter* switch. If the *FL* switch is set to *2.5m-∞*, you will still be able to manually focus from between the MFD of 1.2m and the limited distance of 2.5m, but the lens won't AF in that range.
- The connection between the lens and camera is not being properly made when the lens is mounted.
- You are attempting to use AF on a target that is too dark or too low in contrast to allow your camera's AF to function.
- You are using the lens with an incompatible camera, or via a "dumb" or incompatible adapter.
- You are using the lens with an incompatible or broken teleconverter or extender.
- The AF in the lens is broken.
- The AF in the camera body is broken.